# Erlang - Is there anything in Mnesia similar to ORDER BY in mysql?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I am able to order the obtained data from mnesia but was wondering if it was possible to sort the data while querying from mnesia, similar to using ORDER BY in mysql

Answer (score 1):

If you have `ordered_set` you have already sorted by key. Otherwise, you can use `lists:sort/2`. For sorting by a key deep inside of complex structures or by many of such keys, you could speed up sorting using [Schwartzian_transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) i.e. combination of `lists:sort/1` and two `lists:map/2` or list comprehension. For the bigger amount of data consider [`file_sorter`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file_sorter.html).

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way is to use `ordered_set` table type as [@Hynek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49197/hynek-pichi-vychodil) correctly told. But it is useful to know that `ordered_set` tables time complexity is more than `set` tables in Mnesia.

#### Set

```
| Operation | Average | Worst Case |
|:---------:|:-------:|:----------:|
| Space     | O(n)    | O(n)       |
| Search    | O(1)    | O(n)       |
| Insert    | O(1)    | O(n)       |
| Delete    | O(1)    | O(n)       |
```

#### Ordered Set

```
| Operation | Average  | Worst Case |
|:---------:|:--------:|:----------:|
| Space     | O(n)     | O(n)       |
| Search    | O(log n) | O(n)       |
| Insert    | O(log n) | O(n)       |
| Delete    | O(log n) | O(n)       |
```

If the cost of `ordered_set` table is not tolerable, you can consider using `set` tables and employing an algorithm to make your records ordered. For example a simple and **rough** one could be storing a counter of your records to keep track of their orders and then making your records ordered when writing them. It is important to write them sequentially or use transactions to avoid race conditions. When reading you can fetch desired records one by one based on the order you determined in write phase.